# Why does defining a method called ! break IRB?

Tags: ruby, irb, ruby-2.4

IRB appears to have strange behaviour when defining a method called `!`.

To reproduce this, enter the following into IRB:

```
def !
  puts "foo"
end
```

Upon creating the method, IRB infinitely prints *foo*:

```
irb(main):001:0> def !
irb(main):002:1>   puts "foo"
irb(main):003:1> end
foo
foo
foo
...
```

<s>As far as I know, you can't directly call a method named `!` from Ruby syntax; you have to use `send` instead.</s> *Edit: You can invoke `!` as a prefix operator; it's just negation: `!x`*

Why does this definition cause IRB to loop infinitely? Does IRB rely on a method named `!` for printing its prompt or something similar?

I'm using Ruby 2.4.3 and IRB 0.9.6 on Windows 10.

Comment: You're overriding [`BasicObject#!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-21)

Comment: @Stefan I had no idea it was even possible to override negation. Thanks!

Comment: Ruby is nice in that, if you ask it to slowly burn to death, it will put on a smile and douse itself in gasoline.

Comment: FYI – just type `method(:!)` in IRB to see the method's origin.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo hands you enough rope to shoot your self in the foot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Overriding `!` outside of a class is a *very* weird thing to do! There are countless ways that you can "break" ruby by doing crazy things like this - so you may find it fun to play around with such strange ideas, but obviously don't do this in important code!

In ruby, *all* classes inherit from the top-level base class: `BasicObject`. This class [defines top-level object negation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) - i.e. Whenever you write

```
!foo
```

this is actually calling a *method* called `!` on your object `foo`:

```
foo.send(:!)
```

This makes it possible (although it's a very rare thing to do!) to *redefine* the method on a specific class. For example, when implementing the [null object pattern](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/) you could do something like this:

```
class NullObject
  def !
    true
  end
end

my_null = NullObject.new
!!my_null #=> false
```

(Normally, the *only* objects that would return `false` in the above line are `nil` and `false`!)

Now then, back to your example. What you actually did here was define a method called `!` on the class `Object` (and didn't call `super` to trigger the original method!). In other words, you basically re-defined the response a fundamental method that gets used *all over the place* internally. Something, somewhere (??) got confused by this bizarre behaviour and failed non-gracefully.

```
irb(main):001:0> def !
irb(main):002:1> puts "foo"
irb(main):003:1> super # <-- !! This stops it from breaking completely !!
irb(main):004:1> end
=> :!
irb(main):005:0* method(:!)
foo
foo
=> #<Method: Object#!>
irb(main):006:0> method(:!).source_location
foo
foo
=> ["(irb)", 1]
irb(main):007:0> method(:!).super_method
foo
foo
=> #<Method: BasicObject#!>
```

Here are some other ways you could re-define methods to cause bizarre behaviour/errors, for example:

```
def nil?
  true
end
# Will now die in weird ways!

class String
  def ===(other)
    true
  end
end

"ruby" === "awesome"
#=> true
```